# Check for duplicates before saving them on database

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm pretty new to coding and to Velo from Wix, therefore  I need help.

I created a member's page, the page gets the pricing plan that the member subscribed to, and it shows a specific form to be submitted in order to set a dashboard according to the region he/she selects.

When the user submits the form, my code checks for duplicates like email and field values. If the user has already submitted it an error will appear telling the user that the form was already submitted, if the value is "" or equal to another one, another message will appear and tells the user to check the selection and make 3 different selections.

Well for the Free Plan where only one dropdown is shown, everything runs smoothly, for the Basic where I have 3 dropdowns nothing works. So... let' go to the code:

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady(function () {

        console.log("Ready")

        let user = wixUsers.currentUser

        user.getPricingPlans() 
        .then ((pricingPlans) => {

         let firstPlan = pricingPlans[0];
         let  planName = firstPlan.name;
 
         if (planName == '7 DAY FREE TRIAL $0'){  
         $w('#text30').show();
         $w("#text31").show();
         $w('#dropdown1').show();
         $w('#emailInput').show();
         $w('#button1').show();
         
         searchForDuplicityFreePlan();
         }

         if(planName == 'BASIC'){
         $w('#text30').show();
         $w("#text31").show();
         $w('#dropdown2').show();
         $w('#dropdown3').show();
         $w('#dropdown4').show();
         $w('#emailInput2').show();
         $w('#button2').show();

         searchForDuplicityBasicPlan();

        }  

        }); 

});

async function searchForDuplicityFreePlan(){

        $w("#dataset1").onBeforeSave(async() => {

                let checkEmailFreeOk = await checkEmailFree();
                let fieldCheck = $w("#dropdown1").value;

                if(checkEmailFreeOk === false){
                        $w("#text32").text = "An error occurred. You have already submitted this form";
                   return false     
                }

                if(fieldCheck === ""){
                      $w("#text32").text = "An error occurred. Please select your region of interest";
                   return false       
                }

        })
}

async function checkEmailFree(){

        let flagFree = true

        await wixData.query('RegionSelectionQuizFree')
        .eq('email', $w("#emailInput").value)
        .find()
        .then((result)=>{

             if(result.items.length > 0)   

             flagFree = false

        })

        return await flagFree
}

async function searchForDuplicityBasicPlan(){

        $w("#dataset2").onBeforeSave(async() => {

                let checkEmailBasicOk = await checkEmailBasic();
                let region1 = $w("#dropdown2").value;
                let region2 = $w("#dropdown3").value;
                let region3 = $w("#dropdown4").value;

                const regions = new Set();
                regions.add(region1);
                regions.add(region2);
                regions.add(region3);                
                regions.delete(""); 
               
                if(checkEmailBasicOk === false){
                        $w("#text34").text = "An error occurred. You have already submitted this form";
                        return false     
                } 

                if (regions.size !== 3) {
                    $w("#text34").text = "An error occurred. Please select 3 different regions of interest";
                    return false             
                }

        })
}

async function checkEmailBasic(){

        let flagBasic = true

        await wixData.query('RegionSelectionQuizBasic')
        .eq('email', $w("#emailInput2").value)
        .find()
        .then((result)=>{

             if(result.items.length > 0)   

             flagBasic = false
        })

        return await flagBasic
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a working code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the text edition, @Rojo.

Comment: Seems like `checkEmailBasic` is exactly like `checkEmailFree` except the collection name and the 3 dropdown has nothing with the `checkEmail...` functions. Am I right? If so, the issue is might not related to the validation function itself.  Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Hi @Mosh Feu, you are right about that, I do think the problem is somewhere else, cause if it was in the checkEmail function() wouldn't be working in the first form. The console doesn't show me a thing, I have an error that what I'm doing can't be shown in the console in preview mode.

Comment: Is it a live site? Can you publish your changes and see the logs?